# Mongo DB result Interface to Struct Conversion in Golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm receiving this error when trying to convert interface{} to struct type in golang.

interface conversion: interface {} is primitive.D, not model.ClientModel.
Error in line : cm := res.(model.ClientModel)

```
res, err := db.FindOne(collection, filter)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(res)

    cm := res.(model.ClientModel)
    fmt.Println(cm)
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. What's the question?

Comment: What driver are you using ?  ```FindOne``` returns a ```*SingleResult```  in mongo-driver v1.5+. You can keep it generic until a call to Decode.

Answer (score 1):

You can `.Decode(&foo)` the `SingleResult` returned from `FindOne()`.

```
var cm model.ClientModel
err := db.FindOne(collection, filter).Decode(&cm)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(cm)
```

See https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#SingleResult for details.

Comment: I cannot pass model to decode function as I'm trying to make it work with generic type by passing interface. The result of decode is stored in interface which eventually i want to return outside function and convert to struct in service layer.